# Generate a list of all the hex but those provided

Tags: python

I have to generate a list of all the hex from \x00 to \xff but those provided by the user.

Example:

> generatehex.py 00, 03
>
> \x01\x02\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff

I have used for now this snippet of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if (sys.argv[1]):
    bad_chars = sys.argv[1].split(',')
else:
    print "You must provide the characters that you don't want in the output!"

hex = ["\\x" + format(x, '02x') for x in range(0,256) if (format(x, '02x') not in bad_chars)]

print ''.join(hex)
```

What I want now is to enter a newline every 10 hex printed and the double quote for every line, so:

> generatehex.py 00, 03
>
> "\x01\x02\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b"
>
> "\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15"
>
> "\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f"

and so on, perhaps without the extra newline between rows.

How could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a useful [`grouper` recipe in `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that will handle this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for row in grouper(hex_, 10, ""):
    print "".join(row)
```

Note that you shouldn't name your list `hex`, as that shadows the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex).

Comment: How can I insert also the double quotes before and after each line? Example: "\x01\x02\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b"

Comment: You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make the line look however you want.

Comment: I'd also consider re-writing the bad char exclusion using `bytearray` and `str.translate`, eg: `str(bytearray(range(256))).translate(None, ''.join(chr(int(bad, 16)) for bad in bad_chars.split(',')))` - that way it's using more builtins to quickly generate the valid range and exclude the bad, and offers more validation on the input values instead of using string formatting - then group as you show and format output as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a, b = '\x04', '\xff'
print ''.join([('"' if (i - ord(a)) % 10 == 0 else '')
               + (r'\x' + format(i, r'02x'))
               + ('"\n' if (i - ord(a)) % 10 == 9 else '')
               for i in range(ord(a), ord(b))]) \
               + '"' if not (ord(b) - ord(a)) % 10 == 0 else ''
```

Output:

```
"\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d"
"\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17"
"\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21"
"\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b"
"\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35"
"\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f"
"\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49"
"\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53"
"\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d"
"\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67"
"\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71"
"\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b"
"\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85"
"\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f"
"\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99"
"\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3"
"\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad"
"\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7"
"\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1"
"\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb"
"\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5"
"\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf"
"\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9"
"\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3"
"\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd"
"\xfe"
```